# Can/should I reference library assets outside of the theme folder with relative paths?

Tags: theming

I'm looking at a theme starterkit called [Particle](https://github.com/phase2/particle) that produces output for different apps, including Drupal. Because of this, the directory structure is atypical for a Drupal theme: you put particle in your `themes` directory and the Drupal theme's actual info file is at `particle/apps/drupal`. Built assets like CSS and JS are placed in `particle/dist`. By default it uses an absolute path in [the libraries definition](https://github.com/phase2/particle/blob/master/apps/drupal/particle.libraries.yml):

```
core:
  css:
    theme:
      /themes/particle/dist/app-drupal/assets/app.styles.css:
        preprocess: true
js:
  /themes/particle/dist/app-drupal/assets/app.js:
    preprocess: true
```

I'd rather use a relative path, but I'm aware I'm referencing assets that are outside of the theme: does anyone know if that's likely to cause problems? (Just to be clear, it seems to work fine, but I'm wondering if there might be some gotchas!)

Comment: Yeah that’s absolutely fine, you would use the same principle to load libraries from the root /libraries folder for example

Comment: Thanks @Clive, that makes sense - feel free to add as an answer.